# Private inheritance of std::ostream and using operator<<

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mysqlpp

**Problem:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyClass : private std::ostream
{
public :
    MyClass() : std::ostream(&mBuffer) { }

    using std::operator<<; 


private:
    std::stringbuf mBuffer;
};

// In main function, for example
MyClass c;
c << 'A' << "Hello, World!";  // Works
c << "Hello, World!" << 'A';  // ERROR
```

Error (MS Visual Studio 2010) is error C2666: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<' : 5 overloads have similar conversions

What am I doing wrong or is this another MS Visual Studio bug?

**Workaround:**
Adding the following member method seems to work, but I'd like some insight into the root cause.

```
MyClass& operator<<(const char* str) { 
        std::ostream& os = *this;
        os << str;
        return *this; 
    }
```

**Background:** MySql++ doesn't compile with Visual Studio 2010 (see [mailing list](http://lists.mysql.com/plusplus/9458)) because VS2010 doesn't support public inheritance of (among other things) std::ostream. As a work around, I'm attempting private inheritance as that's less hacking than composition.
MyClass& operator<<(const char* str) { 
        std::ostream& os = *this;
        os << str;
        return *this; 
    }

**Full error message**

```
1>d:\repo\test\test\main.cpp(30): error C2666: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<' : 5 overloads have similar conversions
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(206): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(467): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(851): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const _Elem *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(MyClass, const char [14])'
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Usually template errors are longer. If there is more please post it.

Comment: It's not a template error message as such - but it does list the 5 overloaded methods. I've edited for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a little quirk in the way that stream inserters are defined. Some are members of `ostream`; those are the ones that get picked up by the using declaration. Some are free functions; those take an `stream&` (well, formally, a `basic_ostream<charT>&`), and they won't work with your type. Which is why `c << 'a'` is okay (the inserter for `char` is a member of `ostream`), and `c << "Hello, world!"` doesn't (the inserter for `char*` is not a member function; it requires an `stream&` on its left-hand side). And in `c << 'a' << "Hello, world!"`, the return type of the `c << 'a'` sub-expression is `ostream&`, so the next inserter sees an `ostream&` rather than a `MyClass`, so it's okay at that point.

Your workaround avoids the problem for `char*`, but won't help with other types such as `std::string`, `std::complex`, or any user-defined type.

The right answer is that if you want to create a type that can stand in for an `ostream` you have to implement it as an `ostream`, starting out with public inheritance, and implementing the appropriate overrides.

Comment: Thanks and as per usual so obvious once it's pointed out! - and for the record I know the right answer is public inheritance but that seems to be hitting a documented 'won't fix' bug in VS2010, and issue I'm chasing separately.

Answer (score 3):

Just forward `operator<<` so that it does The Right Thing (TM):

```
class MyClass : private std::ostream
{
public :
    MyClass() : std::ostream(&mBuffer) { }

    template <typename T>
    MyClass& operator<<(T&& t)
    {
        static_cast<std::ostream&>(*this) << std::forward<T>(t);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::stringbuf mBuffer;
};
```

Indeed, some of the stream operators are declared as (friend) free functions, not as a member function of `std::ostream`. Using declarations won't import those.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you meant

```
using std::ostream::operator<<;
```

rather than

```
using std::operator<<;
```